# Possible uses of CCK node-reference and user-reference

Tags: php, drupal, open-source, drupal-6, drupal-7

CCK is gone from Drupal7 and was replaced with the Fields API which is now part of core, but nodereference and userreference were not ported. This creates a problem for me because I use those 2 modules extensively.

There's an effort to work something out to replace these 2 modules with something more compatible with drupal7, but the solution will depend on usage. I'm curious how people are using these 2 modules. Please list your usage below so that the replacement solution takes it into consideration when possible.

I'll start

- I use userreference to give individual permissions to a private node

Comment: This should be a community wiki.

Comment: CCK is not gone from Drupal 7; part of CCK became Drupal core code, but CCK still exists for Drupal 7, and it implements the rest of the code that has not been moved to Drupal, including userreference.module, and nodereference.module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCK will exist in D7 to provide node references, user references, fieldgroups, field-level permissions, and an upgrade path from the D6 CCK API to the D7 Field API. See http://drupal.org/node/533222 for more information.

There's been talk of splitting up the remaining CCK modules into their own separate projects, but I honestly think that will not happen, especially with the upgrade path being important.

Answer (score 4):

I use it only for display only: Relations such A has-one B, A has-many C, that require additional "stuff" are way beyond this module.

e.g. On delete of A, delete all B, or A has-at-least-one B and so on.

So: only when I have a node-type that we, occasionaly want to expand with some display-stuff. Never when we implement true relations.

Another Rule Of Thumb, is that we should have only very few relations. In cases where each node has one-or-more relations, noderelation cannot scale and we implement our own.